# How to count number of functions in particular stage and pass that count to manager.removeBadge(count) in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

i am a beginner and while exploring came across manager.addshortText and remove.Badge() and I want to know how we can count functions / manager.shortText in particular stage in pipeline. So that when I can pass that count in manager.removeBadge(int) in next stage of pipeline.

manager.removeBadge() could help me to skip paritcular number of count to remove label from current build. So that I can display previous label without been removed from previous stage.
So anybody having any idea how we can achieve this in jenkins pipeline?

In advance thankyou!